# How to italic the first letter of a word in \verb|| structure

Tags: verbatim, italic, underscore, underline

How italic the first letter of a word in `\verb||` structure? Suppose that I want have italic (or underscore) for `G` in `\verb|Good|`.

Comment: Do you really need `\verb`?

Comment: If it is possible, I need that. I used this structure in more than 100 words in my work, so It is hard to change it.

Comment: why have you got `Good` in `\verb` ???? the only use of verb is to _disable_ LaTeX formatting and present the characters as a verbatim string. There is no formatting in `Good` to disable so `\verb` is not appropriate, and then you ask to add formatting which seems a strange choice for `\verb`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not sure you're using the right tool for the job and I'd be wary of redefining `\verb`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand\iverb{v}
 {
  \xyz_verbit_split:n { #1 }
 }
\cs_new_protected:Nn \xyz_verbit_split:n
 {
  \texttt
   {
    \underline { \tl_head:n { #1 } }
    \tl_tail:n { #1 }
   }
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\verb|Good|

\iverb|Good|

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Use the abilities of your editor to replace the string `\verb` by `\myverb`. There are also tools that can do it for a bunch of files (in case you have too many files to open them all by hand).

Then add the definition

```
\def\myverb|#1#2|{\texttt{\underline{#1}#2}}
```

to your preamble. It assumes that there is at least one token between the vertical bars.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand\myverb{}% Make sure \myverb is undefined
\def\myverb|#1#2|{\texttt{\underline{#1}#2}}
\begin{document}
\myverb|Good|
\myverb|Goo|
\myverb|Go|
\myverb|G|
%\myverb|| % This gives an error
\end{document}
```

Comment: @CarLaTeX Probably the whole "problem" can be solved by the editor alone. Replacements with regular expressions can take you quite far.